# Count in sql with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table name: `mytable`

```
Id  username  pizza-id  pizza-size  Quantity  order-time
--------------------------------------------------------------
1    xyz         2        9          2        09:00 10/08/2014
2    abc         1        11         3        17:45 13/07/2014
```

This is `mytable` which has 6 columns. `Id` is `int`, `username` is `varchar`, `order-time` is `datetime` and rest are of `integer` datatype.

How to count the number of orders with the following pizza quantities: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7 and above 7?

Using a T-SQL query.

It would be very helpful If any one could help to me find the solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Please provide sample result what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requirement is like count the number of orders with different pizza quantities and represent count of orders as : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7 and consider all above order counts in new category : 'above 7' then you can use window function as:

```
select case when totalorders < = 7 then cast(totalorders as varchar(10)) 
else 'Above 7' end as totalorders
, Quantity 
from 
(
    select distinct count(*) over (partition by Quantity order by Quantity asc) 
    as totalorders,
    Quantity
    from mytable   
) T
order by Quantity
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/LWT46249)</kbd>

Edit: if the requirement is like count the number of orders with pizza quantities: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7 and consider all other pizza quantities in new category : 'above 7' then you can write as:

```
select distinct
count(*) over (
               partition by Quantity order by Quantity asc
              ) as totalorders,
Quantity
from (    
select 
case when Quantity < = 7 then cast(Quantity as varchar(20)) 
else 'Above 7' end as Quantity, id
from mytable   ) T
order by Quantity
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/KFNR23807)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select CASE WHEN Quantity > 7 THEN 'OVER7' ELSE Cast(quantity as varchar) END Quantity, 
COUNT(ID) NoofOrders 
from mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Quantity > 7 THEN 'OVER7' ELSE Cast(quantity as varchar) END
```

or

```
Select

SUM(Case when Quantity = 1  then 1 else 0 end) Orders1,
SUM(Case when Quantity = 2  then 1 else 0 end) Orders2,
SUM(Case when Quantity = 3  then 1 else 0 end) Orders3,
SUM(Case when Quantity = 4  then 1 else 0 end) Orders4,
SUM(Case when Quantity = 5  then 1 else 0 end) Orders5,
SUM(Case when Quantity = 6  then 1 else 0 end) Orders6,
SUM(Case when Quantity = 7  then 1 else 0 end) Orders7,
SUM(Case when Quantity > 7  then 1 else 0 end) OrdersAbove7

from mytable
```

Comment: Are we sure the OP wants 1 row and not 8? Perhaps a complete answer would include both (e.g. `GROUP BY CASE WHEN  Quantity > 7 THEN 'OVER7' ELSE Cast(quantity as varchar) END`

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
SELECT COUNT(ID),CASE WHEN QUANTITY<7 THEN QUANTITY ELSE 'ABOVE7' END AS QUANTITIES 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN QUANTITY<7 THEN QUANTITY ELSE 'ABOVE7' END
```